# How to control colorbar color ranges in Matlab plots?

Tags: matlab, colors, customization, colorbar, colormap

I have the following code:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
crange = 1.5;

[maxval dummy] = max(Z(:));
[minval dummy] = min(Z(:));

% green, yellow, red
cmap = [0 1 0; 1 1 0; 1 0 0];  

figure
colormap(cmap); 
surf(X,Y,Z);
caxis([30 55]);
cbh=colorbar;
set(cbh,'Ytick',[30 32 38 55]);
```

[image]

**My goal** is to set the limits of the color bar so that the colors are like this:

- green from 30 to 32
- yellow from 32 to 38
- red from 38 to 55

I believe I should somehow change the `CData` variable, so I used these lines of code without success:

```
i = findobj(cbh,'type','image');
set(i,'cdata',[30 32 38]','YData',[30 55]);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your custom colorbar consists of `(32-30 = ) 2 + (38-32 = ) 6 + (55-38 = ) 17 = 25` "units" of color. So a simple trick would be replicating each color the required number of "units":

```matlab
function q58097577
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30); Z = (Z - min(Z(:)))*5;

% green, yellow, red
nG = 32-30; nY = 38-32; nR = 55-38;
cmap = [ repmat([0 1 0], [nG 1]); repmat([1 1 0], [nY,1]); repmat([1 0 0], [nR,1]) ];  

figure()
colormap(cmap); 
surf(X,Y,Z);
caxis([30 55]);
cbh=colorbar;
set(cbh,'Ytick',[30 32 38 55]);
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @Federico You're welcome! As you can see, the solution is quite simple but it is only because you have integer colors. It's much nastier when dealing with floats because it's not always clear what should be the size of each "color unit" and so how many of them are needed in total. You could end up with colormaps having some ridiculous number of steps like 7153.